# Wiggling Text Animation (boiling text/line) in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, animation

I want to prefix this by saying: not sure if the post tags are correct, nor do I know the correct term on what exactly I'm trying to achieve.

So, I'm trying to achieve the old school animated text that wiggles / boils / shakes / jitters on all text in my application in winforms (have WPF enabled, but have no idea how it works). Not sure how to properly convey what I'm trying to describe so I will put this example that I could find: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUmzcU8llPQ

If you are an artistic person who knows what to call this kind of effect (usually its keyframed as far as I know), then please share it. it's impossible to find the right term it seems.

I'm on an assignment to create a math quiz application for a hypothetical elementary students to play with, and while I have finished the functionality, what remains is to add some nice cozy style while I still can.

Here is what part of application looks like right now:
[image: first quiz]

I could perhaps animate each letter individually by using keyframes and turning them into gifs or something then displaying a bunch of gifs, however, that seems a roundabout way of doing this and visual studio is already laggy as is without any animation so I would like to avoid overloading it.

I literally have zero idea where to start, and no one seems to have tried this at all before so there is no information I could find either.

lastly, I only have a week left before assignment, so if you think this is not possible to implement in such a short time (especially considering I'm somewhat novice), then please let me know. Worse case scenario, I can scrap it and revert back to a backup if it doesn't work, but I really want that distinction :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the software in the video, but just use Winforms. This can do some simple text effects, you can refer to the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System. ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System. Drawing;
using System. Linq;
using System. Text;
using System. Threading;
using System. Threading. Tasks;
using System. Windows. Forms;

namespace drawing1919
{
     public partial class Form3 : Form
     {
         public Form3()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Graphics Car_Paint = panel1.CreateGraphics();//Instantiate the drawing object
             string Car_Str = "Hello World";//Define the dynamic text to be drawn
             Character character = new Character();//Instantiate a custom class object
             character.CartoonEffect(panel1, Car_Str);//Display dynamic text on the form
         }

         class Character
         {
             System.Drawing.Graphics g;//Define the Graphics object
             static int[] FSize = new int[3] { 20, 25, 30 };//Set font size
             int Str_block = 5;//Interval between fonts
             Font Str_Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", FSize[0], FontStyle.Bold);//Define the font style
             Color Str_Color = Color.Orange;//Define font color
             float Str_Width = 0;//Get the position of the string
             float Str_Height = 0;
             float Panel_W = 0;//Get the width of the control
             float Panel_H = 0;//Get the height of the control
             Color Panel_C;//Record the background color of the control
             float Str_Odd_Width = 0;//Get the width of a single text
             Thread th;//Definition thread

             /// <summary>
             /// Draw animated text in the Panel control
             /// </summary>
             /// <param Panel="C_Panel">Container control for displaying text</param>
             /// <param string="C_Str">Text string</param>
             public void CartoonEffect(Panel C_Panel, string C_Str)
            {
                 g = C_Panel.CreateGraphics();//Create a Graphics object for the control
                 Panel_H = C_Panel.Height;//Get the height of the control
                 Panel_W = C_Panel.Width;//Get the width of the control
                 Panel_C = C_Panel.BackColor;//Get the background color of the control
                 GetTextInfo(C_Str);//Get the size and position of the text
                 g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Panel_C), 0, 0, Panel_W, Panel_H);//Fill the control with the control background
                 ProtractText(C_Str, 0);//draw text
                                        //Instantiate the ParameterizedThreadStart delegate thread
                 th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DynamicText));
                 th.Start(C_Str);//Pass a string parameter
             }

             /// <summary>
             /// Get the size and drawing position of the text
             /// </summary>
             /// <param string="C_Str">Text string</param>
             public void GetTextInfo(string C_Str)
             {
                 SizeF TitSize = g.MeasureString(C_Str, Str_Font);//Format the drawn string
                 Str_Width = TitSize.Width;//Get the width of the string
                 Str_Height = TitSize.Height;//Get the height of the string
                 Str_Odd_Width = Str_Width / (float)C_Str.Length;//Get the width of a single text
                 Str_Width = (float)((Str_Odd_Width + Str_block) * C_Str.Length);//Get the width of the text
                 Str_Width = (Panel_W - Str_Width) / 2F;//Center the text
                 Str_Height = Panel_H - Str_Height;//Make the text display at the bottom of the control
             }

             /// <summary>
             /// Draw all text
             /// </summary>
             /// <param string="C_Str">The drawn text string</param>
             public void ProtractText(string C_Str, int n)
             {
                 float Str_Place = Str_Width;//The position of a single character
                 for (int i = 0; i < C_Str.Length; i++)//traverse the text in the string
                 {
                     if (i != n)
                         ProtractOddText(C_Str[i].ToString(), Str_Font, Str_Place, Str_Height);//Draw a single text
                     Str_Place += Str_Odd_Width + Str_block;//Get the position of the next text
                 }
             }

             /// <summary>
             /// Draw a single text
             /// </summary>
             /// <param name="C_Odd_Str">Single text string</param>
             /// <param name="S_Font">text style</param>
             /// <param name="left"></param>
             /// <param name="top"></param>
             public void ProtractOddText(string C_Odd_Str, Font S_Font, float left, float top)
             {
                 g.DrawString(C_Odd_Str, S_Font, new SolidBrush(Str_Color), new PointF(left, top));//Draw a single text in the string
             }

             /// <summary>
             /// String traversal through iterators
             /// </summary>
             /// <param string="n">Text string</param>
            /// <returns>Return a single text</returns>
             public static IEnumerable<object> Transpose(string n)
             {
                 if (n.Length > 0)//if the generic is not empty
                 {
                     foreach (object i in n)//traversing the string
                         yield return i;
                 }
             }

             /// <summary>
             /// Draw dynamic text
             /// </summary>
             /// <param string="C_Str">The drawn text string</param>
             public void DynamicText(Object C_Str)
             {
                 float tem_left = 0;//Get the left end position of the current text
                 float tem_top = 0;//Get the top position of the current text
                 float tem_w = 0;//Get the width of the text
                 float tem_h = 0;//get the height of the text
                 float tem_place = Str_Width;//Get the position of the starting text
                 Font Tem_Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", FSize[0], FontStyle.Bold);//Define the font style
                 int p = 0;
                 //Record the index number of the text in the string
                 int Str_Index = 0;
                 try
                 {
                     foreach (object s in Transpose(C_Str.ToString()))//traversal string
                     {
                         for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)//
                         {
                             if (i >= 3)
                                 p = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Floor(i/2F));
                             else
                                 p = i;
                             ProtractText(C_Str.ToString(), Str_Index);
                             Tem_Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", FSize[p], FontStyle.Bold);//Define the font style
                             SizeF TitSize = g.MeasureString(s.ToString(), Str_Font);//Format the drawn single text
                             tem_w = TitSize.Width;//Get the width of the text
                             tem_h = TitSize.Height;//Get the height of the text string
                             tem_left = tem_place - (tem_w - Str_Odd_Width) / 2F;//Get the left end position of the text after changing the size
                             tem_top = Str_Height - (Str_Height - tem_h) / 2F;//Get the top position of the text after changing the size
                             ProtractOddText(s.ToString(), Tem_Font, tem_left, tem_top);//Draw a single text
                             Thread.Sleep(200);//wait for 0.2 seconds
                             g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Panel_C), 0, 0, Panel_W, Panel_H);//clear the drawn text
                         }
                         tem_place += Str_Odd_Width + Str_block;//Calculate the left end position of the next text
                         Str_Index += 1;//position the index number to the next text
                     }
                     ProtractText(C_Str.ToString(), -1);//Restore the original drawing style of the text
                                                        //Instantiate the ParameterizedThreadStart delegate thread
                     th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DynamicText));
                     th.Start(C_Str);//Pass a string parameter
                 }
                 catch//The reason why the exception statement is used here is to close the thread when closing the form
                 {
                     th.Abort();//Close the thread
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, though this doesn't achieve what I want. Rather than the size changing, I want the lines to "wiggle", keyframed example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iq5VnJ2c-eY.

You mentioned if I don't want to use the app in the video, well I can, just not sure how can connect it to my form without lagging it. I can even draw the letters using a few keyframes on a loop, just not sure how I can apply that to all text in my application in winforms. The mathquiz HAS to be in winforms.

Hopefully this makes sense, otherwise I'm happy to elaborate further.

Comment: @Firefingertips I don't know much about this software, but I have an opinion. You can use ScreenToGif to make wobbly text into a gif. Then use picturebox in your winforms to play those gifs. "pictureBox1.Enabled = true/false;" can control the gif to start or stop playing.